# Slice collection multiple times

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection with a bunch of data.

I am trying to do the following

- get the first 18 results and spit them out
- get the first 3 results for a particular where using a loop and spit each out

Here is an example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
$data = DataChampion::query()
    ->selectRaw('
        static_champions.name as champion_name, static_champions.slug as champion_slug, static_champions.image as champion_image,
        static_lanes.slug as lane_slug, static_tiers.slug as tier_slug, static_patches.slug as patch_slug,
        ((sum(data_champions.wins) / sum(data_champions.matches)) * 100) as win_rate
    ')
    ->leftJoin('static_champions', 'static_champions.id', 'data_champions.static_champion_id')
    ->leftJoin('static_lanes', 'static_lanes.id', 'data_champions.static_lane_id')
    ->leftJoin('static_tiers', 'static_tiers.id', 'data_champions.static_tier_id')
    ->leftJoin('static_patches', 'static_patches.id', 'data_champions.static_patch_id')
    ->where('data_champions.static_patch_id', StaticPatch::orderByDesc('id')->first()->id)
    ->groupBy('data_champions.static_champion_id')
    ->orderByDesc('win_rate')
    ->get();

foreach ($data->splice(0, 18) as $data) {
    echo $data->champion_name . '<br>';
}

foreach (['top', 'middle', 'bottom'] as $lane_slug) {
    foreach ($data->where('lane_slug', $lane_slug)->splice(0, 3) as $data) {
        echo $lane_slug . ' - ' . $data->champion_name . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::splice()

When I remove the `foreach (['top', 'middle'...` entire loop it seems to work for the first 18 results.

How do I get the data I want from the single collection so I don't have to use multiple queries with the same data?

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you are adding a where in that foreach, the  collection becomes to an query builder, try to add a ->get()  after that where

Answer (score 0):

Change a few lines as below - You cannot use the same variable name while iterating the collection (i.e $data).

```
foreach ($data->splice(0, 18) as $val) {
    echo $val->champion_name . '<br>';
}

foreach (['top', 'middle', 'bottom'] as $lane_slug) {
    foreach ($data->where('lane_slug', $lane_slug)->splice(0, 3) as $val) {
        echo $lane_slug . ' - ' . $val->champion_name . '<br>';
    }
}
```